# How can I pass parameters between two Activity but one must only support the first one

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, intentservice

I have an activity that very quickly has to process data and then return to the previous activity, I give an example: I have a MainActivity class that passes information through Intent to another Loader class, this processes the data and sends it back to the MainActivity. I don't know how to put this procedure into practice...

Comment: Using _startActivityForResult()_

Comment: After using it you need  to send data back to previous activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your MainActivity call the TargetActivity using  startActivityForResult()-

**For example:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(); // sent your putExtra data here to pass through intent
startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

In your intent set the data which you want to return back to MainActivity. If you don't want to return back any data then you don't need to set any data.

**For example:**

In TargetActivity if you want to send back data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result", result);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

If you don't want to return data:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Now in your MainActivity class write following code for the onActivityResult() method.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1000) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
        }
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Do your task here. 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the help of android startActivityForResult() method, you can get result from another activity.

By the help of android startActivityForResult() method, you can send information from one activity to another and vice-versa. The android startActivityForResult method, requires a result from the second activity (activity to be invoked).

In such case, we need to override the onActivityResult method that is invoked automatically when second activity returns result.

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
    TextView textView1;  
    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
        textView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
        button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);  
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);// Activity is started with 
                                                    requestCode 2  
            }  
        });  
    } 

 // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity  
    @Override  
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  
       {  
                 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  
                  // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2  
                   if(requestCode==2)  
                         {  
                            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");   
                            textView1.setText(message);  
                         }  
     }
```

SecondActivity.java

```
 public class SecondActivity extends Activity {  
    EditText editText1;  
    Button button1;  
    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);  
        editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
            button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                    String message=editText1.getText().toString();  
                    Intent intent=new Intent();  
                    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",message);  
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);  
                    finish();//finishing activity  
                }  
            });  
    }  
    @Override  
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);  
        return true;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This must be `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);`  instead of `setResult(2,intent);`

Comment: I compared request code== 2 instead of Activity.RESULT_OK in onActivityResult(). Thats why i send 2 as request code.

Comment: request code is different and result code is different.

Comment: Yes i know bt here i want to give simple basic example thats wy i used 2. 2 in setResult() in SecondActivity doesn't has any meaning in MainActivity code because i am checking request code only not result code

Comment: I know but it will confuse OP

Answer (score 0):

```
//do Some work
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity2..class);
startActivityForResult(i,12);
}
```

In MainActivity2.class

```
// after your work complete
Intent i =new Intent();
i.putExtra("result",true);// any data you want to pass
setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
```

After this we handle result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

switch(requestCode){

case 12:
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){// onsuccess do something

             boolean isSucces = data.getBooleanExtra("result",false);

     if(isSuccess)// perform action
{// show toast}
}
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the best to use callbacks.

in Loader:
Create inner class

```
    MyCallback callback;

viod setCallback(MyCallback callback){
this.callback = callback;
}
viod onStop(){
    callback = null;
}

interface MyCallback{
    void doSomething(Params params);
}
```

in MainActivity:
implement MyCallback
set reference in onCreate

```
Loader loader = new Loader();
loader.setCallback(this);

override method doSomething()
@override
void doSomething(Params params){
 //do your thing with the params…
}
```

when the job is done inside Loader call MainActivity:

```
callback.doSomething(params);
```

destroy reference inside MainActivity in onStop()

```
loader.onStop();
```